# Installation of compatible Android DDMS from eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ddms

I updated android development environment after which I had `Android DDMS 12.x.x`, `ADT 21.1.0`, `Android Hierarchy viewer 12.0.0`, `Android Native Development Tools 21.1.0`, `Android Traceview 12.0.0` installed on my `eclipse helios 3.6.0`. I could not update `Android DDMS`, `Android Hierarchy viewer`, and `Android Traceview to 21.x.x` because of some dependencies issues. So I thought of giving it a hit and trial manually by uninstalling and then installing these old features. I uninstalled `Android DDMS`, but now I cannot get it installed as only version 21.x.x shows in the update which is incompatible because of dependencies.

So how can I now, if possible, install stand alone `DDMS` to the latest version or even revert back to the older working version of 12.x.x?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Update1: I tried reverting the changes from installation history in eclipse, but now all I get is

> No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,12.0.0.v201106281929-138431

Update2: Even though I (Help > About Eclipse SDK > Installation Details) uninstalled the DDMS, I still have DDMS perspective so I wonder if it is really uninstalled at all. Only that DDMS doesn't show now in "Installed software". How can I get it back there in the installed softwares?

No luck till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was apprehensive about installing the things all over. That was the reason I had
Android DDMS 12.x.x , ADT 21.1.0, Android Hierarchy viewer 12.0.0, Android Native Development Tools 21.1.0, Android Traceview 12.0.0 installed on my eclipse helios 3.6.0 after performing update. These inconsistent versions were largely due to the plugin dependency issues.

As mentioned above reverting back also didn;t work. So I had to uninstall all these plugins. Somehow then installing the fresh and latest version of plugins also didn;t work. Then I downloaded the older version of ADT that I was using before updating from

[dl.google.com/android/ADT-12.0.0.zip](http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-12.0.0.zip)

(Found the link for old ADT from one of the answers in stackoverflow. I dont know why google doesn;t provide the links to old repositories)
Then I installed it and after performing the updates I have all the plugins with version 21.x.x.

P.S The eclipse version was also upgraded to 3.6.2.

This is the work around I found. And **Never try to fix the things that are not broken.**